# How to catch php redirect in js XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to catch php header('Location: ...'); in my vanilla js code, via XMLHttpRequest?

js:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/admin/edit', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.getAllResponseHeaders());
}

xhr.send();
```

---

php:

```
header("Location: /admin/login");
```

---

browser:

[image: but status don't change]
**status don't change**
**location not specified**

[image]

---

[image]

**i need catch redirect before request login.**

Comment: have you tried using the `xhr.status` to monitor for `302` status codes?

Comment: You’re going to need to do this in the `readystatechange` handler. Currently, you are only reacting when the `load` event occurs, but by then it is already to late.

Comment: through readystatechange nothing changes

Answer (score -1):

If you were to use the `readystatechange` event handler within the body of your ajax function you can monitor the `status` of the request and fork logic accordingly - like this perhaps:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onstatuschange=function(){

        if( this.readyState==4 ){
            if(  this.status==200 ){
                console.log(this.getAllResponseHeaders());
                callback( this.response )
            }
            if( this.status==302 ){
                alert( this.status )
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', '/admin/edit', true);
    xhr.send();
```

Comment: The status will never be reported as 302. XHR follows redirects transparently.

Comment: it does if you use `http_response_code( 302 );`

Comment: It doesn't matter what mechanism you use to make the server emit a 302 redirect. The redirect will be followed **transparently**.

Comment: so I just learned